# How to Locate Private Key/JSON file of Account Created in Geth terminal

Tags: private-key, keystore

Software: Ubuntu on Virtual Box

---

I created test account in geth terminal (rinkeby network), i.e., but I am not finding keystore, or json file in

`home\rinkeby\keystore`

Please assist

can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify the datadir parameter (eg, geth --datadir "your directory" account new) where you are storing the chaindata? If you didn't specify a datadir parameter so it's probably in the default geth location. The datadir parameter is different to the ipcpath parameter. Or you could run a search on your computer for directory names "chaindata" or "keystore" .

Comment: No, I didn't. This is first I am hearing of `--datadir`

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: ok let me try ....

Comment: Ahhh, your answer helps ..... I'm gonna start over (teaching myself this fascinating technology!)